# Why do UDP and TCP include the sender port number aswell as the receiver port number when they exchange packets?

Tags: tcp, udp

Why do UDP and TCP include the sender port number aswell as the receiver port number
when they exchange packets?

Comment: How else would you distinguish packets from two different applications running on the same machine?

Answer (score 3):

In the case of UDP, so you can reply to the sender, via the 'from'-address returned by `recvfrom().`

In the case of TCP, to identify the connection. A TCP connection is identified by the unique 4-tuple

```
{source IP, source port, target IP, target port}
```

All this information is therefore required to identify the connection for which a packet is intended.

Answer (score 0):

They do that for the same reason you address a letter not to a city, but to city, street and person and you do the same when specifying the sender of the letter. Otherwise the addresses are not complete.

Answer (score -1):

IP address at the network layer has the machine to which the packet has to be sent. Once the packet reach the machine the port numbers at the transport layer indicates the application to which the data has to be send. Each port number uniquely identifies an application on the system.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He is asking why the *sender* port number.